# How to get BCM4312 driver to work properly?

Tags: 11.04, wireless, broadcom

I have a Dell Laptop on which wireless and every thing used to work perfectly.Today morning I noticed the suddenly there is no wireless at all.
On a working condition I used to have folllowing

```
lspci -vnn

0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:000c]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at f69fc000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: wl, ssb
```

and

```
/etc/lsb-release
Ubuntu 11.04 64 bit
```

Module in use was wl.ko But now all of a sudden it fails to load any module for wireless.I have no idea why this happened.I am a SOHO user who does not have any thing other than web surfing and multimedia to do on this machine.I even booted from a Live USB but still wireless here failed to work (prior to installation same Live USB was able to detect the wifi card and wireless worked with this live USB).
The driver in use was found on the LIVE cd at following location

```
pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_5.100.82.38+bdcom-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
```

which used to show as additional drivers available for  installation.Now this option even does not come when I boot with this Live USB.Since the installation of Ubuntu I have kept this Live USB as a backup. Can some one help here?

Comment: This is not a question that can be simply answered. Troubleshooting wireless that used to work usually requires an exchange of posts to gather additional information, which is more suitable for a forum or irc chat. I'd recommend http://ubuntuforums.org.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please remove any installed drivers in "Additional drivers". Then reboot your computer and reinstall the driver. Reboot once again and hopefully, your wireless driver will work properly.

Comment: yes this worked like a charm seems 11.04 have a problem in wireless driver I need to put 11.10 on the machine.